# Call a python script inside a modelica model

Tags: python, c, modelica

I am trying to create a Modelica model to be exported into a FMU. This Modelica model needs to call a Python 3 code and I just cannot manage to include it in my model. I have found this [Interoperability - C and Pyton](https://openmodelica.ida.liu.se/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/interop_c_python.html) explanation of how to. But it does not give the structure of the python script.

To follow this tutorial I have written the pyRunString.py script as:

```
def pyRunString(s):
    print(s)
```

And I get compilation errors:

> In file included from CallExternalPython_functions.c:7:0:
>   CallExternalPython_includes.h: In function 'pyRunString':
>   CallExternalPython_includes.h:9:21: warning: passing argument 1 of
>   'Py_SetProgramName' from incompatible pointer type
>   [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] Py_SetProgramName("pyRunString"); /*
>   optional but recommended */ ^ In file included from
>   C:/Users/cabecerrilaguirre/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/include/Python.h:140:0,
>   from CallExternalPython_includes.h:5, from
>   CallExternalPython_functions.c:7:
>   C:/Users/cabecerrilaguirre/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/include/pylifecycle.h:40:18:
>   note: expected 'const wchar_t * {aka const short unsigned int *}' but
>   argument is of type 'char *' PyAPI_FUNC(void) Py_SetProgramName(const
>   wchar_t *);

Then I have commented the line

```
Py_SetProgramName(\"pyRunString\"); /* optional but recommended */
```

And got:

> CallExternalPython_functions.o:CallExternalPython_functions.c:(.text+0xb):
>   undefined reference to `__imp_Py_Initialize'
>   CallExternalPython_functions.o:CallExternalPython_functions.c:(.text+0x18):
>   undefined reference to`__imp_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
>   CallExternalPython_functions.o:CallExternalPython_functions.c:(.text+0x24):
>   undefined reference to `__imp_Py_Finalize' collect2.exe: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status CallExternalPython.makefile:32: recipe for
>   target 'omc_main_target' failed mingw32-make: *** [omc_main_target]
>   Error 1 mingw32-make: Leaving directory
>   'C:/Users/CABECE~1/AppData/Local/Temp/OPENMO~1' RESULT: 2

Could somebody help me undrestand what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: I do not understadn the details of you problem but could reccommend as an alternative https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/Modelica-ExternalLibrary , which works at least in Dymola to call Python code from Modelica. You then can export the Modelica code as FMU (calling the python code).